# I cannot get my $.ajax request to fire on a button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

I have checked my variables and they all come out as expected, the ajax request works if I paste it outside of the `.on()` event.  Then if I just post the same request into my `.on()` it breaks down.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var searchData;
    var titles;
    var descriptions;
    var websites;

    $(".clicked").on("click", function() {  
      var keyword = document.querySelector('#search').value; 
      // This alert succeeded
      alert(keyword);
      var apiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + keyword + "&namespace=0&limit=10";
      // This alert succeeded and returned correct concat
      alert(apiURL);
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + keyword + "&namespace=0&limit=10",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // This alert fails
            alert("did this work?")
            searchData = data;
            titles = searchData[1];
            descriptions = searchData[2];
            websites = searchData[3];
            for (i=1; i<titles.length; i++) {
                $("body").append("<div class=\"query\"><a href=" + websites[i] + "\"><h1>" + titles[i] + "</h1><p>" + descriptions[i] + "</p></a></div>");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Are you adding `.clicked` element dynamically? Check if the `click` event is triggering? place an alert within click event..

Comment: Yes, the click event triggers.  I put in alerts to let me know if the value of `var keyword` was populating from the `<input>` as well... and it is.

Comment: Did you try alert on your `success: function()`

Comment: Alert just inside the click succeeded.  Alert inside the success function failed.

Comment: Check if you have any console errors. Also try to attach `error` callback to your `ajax` function.

Comment: Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/servantofgrace/full/JLYNGV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure why this worked, but i added `e.preventDefault();` directly before the `$.ajax` call and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please do verify the following things

1) Ensure that the selector is correct.

2) If the clickable content is loaded by ajax function then try to live click function.

3) And you can track through the network option in browser dev tools whether it is initiated or not.

Comment: The selector is correct.  The click is a submit button on a search form.  The ajax request is through the wikipedia api to populate search results.  When I put the ajax inside the click even it doesn't show as initiated in the dev tools.  I added the codepen above if you'd like to take a look.